# Collapse a matrix to sum values in one column by values in another

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with three columns: county, date, and number of ED visits. The dates repeat for each county, like this (just an example):

```
  County A  1/1/2012  2
  County A  1/2/2012  0
  County A  1/3/2012  5
  ... etc.
  County B  1/1/2012  3
  County B  1/2/2012  4
  ... etc.
```

I would like to collapse this matrix to sum the visits from all counties for each date. So it would look like this:

```
1/1/2012  5
1/2/2012  4
etc.
```

I am trying to use the `"table()"` function in R but can't seem to get it to operate on visits by date in this manner.  When I do `"table(dt$date, dt$Visits)"` it gives me a table of frequencies like this:

```
             0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  2011-01-01 3 1 2 0 1 1 0 2 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2011-01-02 2 3 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0  2  0  0  0  0  0
  2011-01-03 3 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Any suggestions?  Is there a better function to use, perhaps a "sum" of some sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DWin states, `table()` is not for summation, but for record counts.

I give three examples of approaches, using `plyr`, `data.table` and `aggregate`

```
all_data <- expand.grid(country = paste('Country', LETTERS[1:3]), 
  date = seq(as.Date('2012/01/01'), as.Date('2012/12/31'), by = 1) )

all_data[['ed_visits']] <- rpois(nrow(all_data), lambda = 5)



# using plyr

library(plyr)

by_date_plyr <- ddply(all_data, .(date), summarize, visits = sum(ed_visits))


# using data.table
library(data.table)
all_DT <- data.table(all_data)
by_date_dt <- all_DT[, list(visits = sum(ed_visits)), by = 'date' ]

# using aggregate
by_date_base <- aggregate(ed_visits ~ date, data = all_data, sum)
```

Answer (score 5):

`table()` is not for summation of values, it is for record counts. If you want to use `tapply` you get a table output and can apply the `sum` function. Or you can use `ave` to get a sum vector of equal length as the dataframe. Perhaps:

```
  with( EDcounts, tapply(EDcounts[[3]], EDcounts[[2]], sum, na.rm=TRUE) )
```

You maybe able to coax `xtabs` into summation of visit counts as well if you put the "visits" column name on the LHS of the formula.

Comment: Thank you!  Tapply worked wonderful.  Never seen that "with" before- cool!

Comment: `with` will simplify your console work considerably. It's help page warns that it can lead to errors inside functions as can the use of "$" as a function.